# Memory error while importing IMDb files using IMDbPY script

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, imdbpy

While importing the IMDb files into MySQL 5 using MyISAM storage engine I am getting the following memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 3072, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 2937, in run
    readMovieList()
  File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 1531, in readMovieList
    mid = CACHE_MID.addUnique(title, yearData)
  File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 1135, in addUnique
    else: return self.add(key, miscData)
  File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 1010, in add
    self[key] = c
  File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 922, in __setitem__
    dict.__setitem__(self, key, counter)
MemoryError
```

This is on Ubuntu 14.0.4 an EC2 instance on AWS with 1GB of memory.  I first tried using this command:

```
imdbpy2sql.py --mysql-force-myisam -d /home/ubuntu/imdb-files/ -u mysql://admin:password@localhost/imdb
```

And also:

```
imdbpy2sql.py --mysql-force-myisam -d /home/ubuntu/imdb-files/ -u mysql://admin:password@localhost/imdb -c /home/ubuntu/imdb-files/csv
```

Both failed with the same memory error.  Anyone know of a workaround?

**UPDATE (6/20/2015):**

It always produces this memory error at the same point.  Here is the MySQL table status of the title table it is populating.

| Name            | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows    | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length  | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment

| title           | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    | 2699999 |             83 |   226543136 |  281474976710655 |     32410624 |         0 |        2700000

And the memory usage of imdbpy2sql.py is around 62%.  I am not a Python pseron so not sure how to debug it so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that 1 GB of total RAM is not enough to run imdbpy2sql.py safely. Maybe you can try on a different instance or adding a swap file to your system (it will obviously slow everything down).

Comment: I agree with that, I did install it on my local machine (2GB RAM) and it worked.  On another note, if you have insight into this issue it would be greatly appreciated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028657/mysql-missing-soundtrack-information-after-running-imdbpy2sql-py